# Incrementing a variable in Javascript not working?

Tags: javascript

I have created a basic score counter using a variable.

Basically what happens is when you click a box, if the variable `findbomb` is equal to the parameter of the function choice, then it will say you won and it should add 1 to the variable `score` but if the variable `findbomb` is different than the parameter `num` then if will say you lost and take 1 away from the score.

But for some reason even though I am using `score++` to increment the variable it refuses to do so and no errors pop up inside of the developers menu in Chrome.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Assignment</title>

    <style>
        body{background:black;}


        #game{width:1282px;
              position:absolute;top:15%;left:50%;
              margin-left:-642px;}

        #background{width:1282px;}

        #covered{width:1282px;
                 position:absolute;left:50%;top:70%;
                 margin-left:-642px;
                 z-index:100;}

        #filled{width:1282px;
                position:absolute;top:70%;
                z-index:50;}

        #box0{position:absolute;;left:20%;}

        #box1{position:absolute;left:60%;}


        .bombonleft{position:absolute;left:20%;}
        .blankonright{position:absolute;left:60%;}


        .blankonleft{position:absolute;left:20%;}
        .bombonright{position:absolute;left:60%;}

        #rules{width:500px;
               text-align:center;
               background:red;
               position:absolute;top:10%;left:50%;
               margin-left:-250px;
               z-index:300;
               display:none;}


        #feedback{position:absolute;left:50%;top:10%;
                  margin-left:-300px;
                  width:600px;
                  height:auto;
                  font-size:200%;
                  font-family:sans-serif;
                  text-align:center;
                  background:red;
                  display:none;}

        #scores{position:absolute;top:10%;left:5%;
               width:50px;
               text-align:center;
               font-size:300%;
               font-family:sans-serif;
               background:red;}

        #timer{position:absolute;top:30%;left:50%;
               margin-left:-236px;}

        #countdown{width:300px;
                   text-align:center;
                   position:absolute;
                   left:50%;
                   top:35%;
                   font-family:sans-serif;
                   font-size:1000%;
                   margin-left:-150px;
                   color:red;
                 }

        #title{text-align:center;
               font-family:sans-serif;
               font-size:300%;
               color:red;
               }
        #finder{background:red;}

        #new{background:red;}
    </style>


</head>

<body> 
    <div id="title">
        <p>Find the Bomb!</p>
    </div>

    <div id ="game">


      <div id="covered">  
            <img id="box0" src="closed.png" onclick="choose(0);">
            <img id="box1" src="closed.png" onclick="choose(1);">
        </div>

        <div id="filled">
          <img id ="bomb" class="bombonright" src="bomb .png">
          <img id="blank" class="blankonleft" src="empty.png">
      </div>

       <div id="background">
         <div id="scores"> 2 </div>
            <img id="backround"src="new background.png">    
       </div>

       <div id="buttons">
         <button id="Restartbtn" onclick="start();">Restart</button>
         <button id="Rulesbtn" onclick = "showrules();">?</button>
      </div>

        <div id="rules">
            <p> You awake to find yourself locked in this room with two boxes at your feet.</p>
            <p> A voice comes over a speaker and states "Welcome, you have been chosen to take part in a little game. At your feet you will find two boxes. One is empty and the other contains a enough explosives to reduce you to dust. The aim of the game is simple find the bomb.</p>
            <p> However, there are some rules</p>
            <p> Firstly you must make a choice within 5 seconds , otherwise the bomb explodes. There is a timer that counts down so be ware<p>
            <p> You may only choose one box </p>
            <p> Choose correctly and you may advance to the next round <p>
            <p> If you survive a round you will get a point ,once you have 5 you will be set free <p>
            <p> However if you fail to find the bomb , you will lose a point. Once you score hits -5 , the bomb will detonat<p>
            <p> The game begins as soon as you press close on this message, if you need to select it again press the "?" button<p>

            <button onclick="hiderules();"> CLOSE </button>
        </div>

      <div id="feedback">
            You lost! <br>Fortunately this bomb was a fake!
        </div>
<div id="timer">
      <img src="timer.png">
    </div>

        <div id="countdown">
            2:00
        </div>

        <div id="finder">
        fdafdsfa
        </div>

      <div id="new">
        2ffdaj
        </div>

    </div>

    <script>
        var findbomb=1;
        var clickable = false;
        var score = 0;

        window.onload = start();findme();newscore();

        function findme()
            {document.getElementById('finder').innerHTML = findbomb;}   

        function newscore()
            {document.getElementById('new').innerHTML = score;};

        function start()
            {score=0;
             showscore();
             setup();};

        function showscore()
            {document.getElementById('scores').innerHTML= score;};

        function hidebox()
            {document.getElementById('box0').style.display = "block";
             document.getElementById('box1').style.display = "block";};

        function hidefeedback() 
            {document.getElementById('feedback').style.display =  "none";};

        function showbfeedback()
            {document.getElementById('feedback').style.display = "block";
             setTimeout(setup, 1000);
            };

        function showrules()
            {document.getElementById('rules').style.display = "block";};

        function hiderules()
            {document.getElementById('rules').style.display = "none";};

        function play()
            { findbomb = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);

              if (findbomb == 0)
                {document.getElementById('bomb').setAttribute("class", "bombonleft");
                 document.getElementById('blank').setAttribute("class", "blankonright");}

              else if (findbomb == 1)
                {document.getElementById('bomb').setAttribute("class", "bombonright");
                 document.getElementById('blank').setAttribute("class", "blankonleft");}

             clickable=true;

            };

        function setup()
            {hidefeedback();
             hidebox();
             play();};

        function choose(num)
            {if (clickable = true)
                {document.getElementById('box'+num).style.display = "none";

                    if(findbomb ==num)
                        {document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "You Win"; score++;}
                    else if (findbomb != num)
                        {document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML ="You lose, fortunately that one was a fake!";score--;};

                    setTimeout(showbfeedback, 1000);
                    clickable= false;   
                }
            }


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well every one starts some where.. :) You tried, that's what counts. In choose function, try changing this to this: `{document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "You Win"; score++; showscore()}`

Comment: tanjir thank you , you are a saint!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `window.onload` to a *function*.  Not to `undefined`.

When you do `window.onload = start();`, you are *calling* `start()` *immediately* and assigning its *return value* (`undefined`) to `window.onload` - which does nothing.

You want to do either:

```
window.onload = start;
```

or:

```
window.onload = function(){
    start();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

So when you have an issue like this, you should either print the expected values out at certain points, or better yet, use breakpoints and then walk thru the code. In this case, just open the page in a browser like Chrome and then open the developer tools (f12 in chrome). You then set a breakpoint and walk forward one step at a time.

Ah, and I see your comment now about nothing showing in developer tools. So that means you need to go back to square one to figure out why your code is not getting executed, which has nothing to do with your variable set up.

Comment: Hey @MattC I'm the MattC in California, you have impeccable taste in anime, sir.  Upped because all MattCs deserve no less.

Answer (score 0):

The score is not showing, because it needs to be updated on the html page.

Try putting something like this after the last if else if clause:

`document.getElementById('scores').innerHTML = ""+score;`

This should update your score on the page.